# How to calculate metrics for one particular column from other columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, data-analysis, data-science

I have a dataset where I need to calculate metrics related to each person on a dataset. For example, I have a dataframe with data that looks like this

```
id   name    age   task_date    task_venue   money_earned
1    John    25    2016-05-01      A             100
2    Jane    28    2016-05-12      A             120
1    John    25    2016-05-03      B             150
3    Suse    21    2016-05-30      B             200
...
```

So, what I need to do is calculate metrics for each person `John, Jane, Suse` etc., such as `Time Since Last Task`, `Average Earnings`, `Total Earnings`, `Total Tasks Done` and so on.

The real dataset is large (around 1M rows and has a lot more columns ~50 and ~75K persons), but this explains essentially what I need to do.

What would be the most efficient way to take this dataframe and do those calculations? I'd prefer do use pandas functions but pure python would also work as long as I can save the result in another dataframe?

Answer (score 3):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) metrics like for column `money_earned` `mean` and `sum`, for column `task_venue` `size` and so on:

```
print (df.groupby('name').agg({'money_earned':['mean', sum], 'task_venue': len}))
     task_venue money_earned     
            len         mean  sum
name                             
Jane          1          120  120
John          2          125  250
Suse          1          200  200
```

[Aggregation in pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation).

---

After aggregation you get [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html) in columns, you can flat it by `list comprehension`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('name').agg({'money_earned':['mean', sum], 'task_venue': len})
df1.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
print (df1)
      task_venue_len  money_earned_mean  money_earned_sum
name                                                     
Jane               1                120               120
John               2                125               250
Suse               1                200               200
```

---

If need aggregate custom function use:

```
df.task_date = pd.to_datetime(df.task_date)

def f(x):
    #print (x)
    return x.min() + pd.Timedelta('3d')

df1 = df.groupby('name').agg({'money_earned':['mean',sum], 'task_venue': len, 'task_date':f})
df1.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in df1.columns]
print (df1)
      task_venue_len task_date_f  money_earned_mean  money_earned_sum
name                                                                 
Jane               1  2016-05-15                120               120
John               2  2016-05-04                125               250
Suse               1  2016-06-02                200               200
```

---

If aggregation is slow, because big `DataFrame`, I suggest [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.reduction`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.reduction).

Comment: thank you for the answer. this certainly points me in the right direction. one thing I'd like to add is if I need a custom function instead of the regular mean, sum, length that use one or more columns for calculations, what could be my approach? I'd essentially want to calculate each metric one at a time and perhaps merge everything in the end?

Comment: I add custom function - 3 days are added to minimal datetime  per group.